# Is there a way to stimulate notion rate limit to test locally. I dont have a large notion pages

Tags: notion-api

In my production app a user tried to integrate notion. but got this error after sometime

```
'{"object":"error","status":429,"code":"rate_limited","message":"You have been rate limited. Please try again in a few minutes.","request_id":"e5eac1d6-8116-4b7e-9df5-d96208275b4a"}'
```

I want to do a fix on this by limiting also I want to test. I can't seem to find a way to simulate in local as I cannot use users notion for testing and it takes some time to get this error. Any method to simulate in local without loading a hefty pages in my personal notion?